# Images in html inside div don't appear below each other (please see the pic)?

Tags: css, html

Why images appear in such manner , .. ?

```
    <div id='container'>  
      <div class='imgContainer'>
         <div  class='myLocation'>
              <img src='https://graph.facebook.com/1055505/picture' style='width:30px'>
              Tova Schherr
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class='imgContainer'>
         <div  class='myLocation'>
              <img src='https://graph.facebook.com/1205050/picture' style='width:30px'>
              Alison Carmel
         </div>
      </div>

..... .. 
 ...... 
</div>
```

you must know that the data are sample to show the example, so it will not work.

here is CSS class for myLocation

```
.myLocation
{
    margin-bottom:1px;
    width:100%;

    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:#006699;
    padding:7px;
    padding-right:12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have already done, but nothing !!!

Comment: can you post the code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, your doctype require to close the image tag.

```
<img src="" />
```

Comment: Yeah. Doctype can be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fixed height on .imgContainer

```
.imgContainer {
    height:80px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```